# javascript works on page but not respods on iframe page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

java-script works on page but not responds on i frame page

Im working in a basic php page(ill call it home.php), I'm trying to code a progress bar that moves from left to right (onclick using JS).  The problem i have is I'm using iframes to load in "set content", when the user clicks on "set content" via iframs, it appears the progress bar will only respond to code on the home page(it seems to ignore any js code on a page which is loaded using iframes).

if you want more details here is the code:

```
<!--SCRIPT ON HOME PAGE:-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

 <div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div id="myBar" class="w3-container w3-green" style="height:24px;width:1%"></div>
</div>

<button class="w3-button w3-light-grey" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function move() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 24);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 20) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
        }
    }


}

</script> 
<!--SCRIPT ON HOME PAGE-->


<!--SCRIPT ON PHP PAGE LOADED IN USING iframes-->
<button class="tablinks" onclick="move()">My Resume</button>
<!--SCRIPT ON PHP PAGE LOADED IN USING iframes-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, you can call to a "move" function belong to the parent page from an iframe by calling `parent.move()`. But, now you need to care about CSP - [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) too.

Open the console to see if something like "Blocked a frame with origin..." appears. Then fix it by updating the CSP until it works.

Comment: actually im getting an error message in console: "ReferenceError: move is not defined"

Comment: okay, have an update! not sure if i didn't explain my problem well enough, but i think i have found a solution (at least one that dose not generate errors in console!).  your talking about parents got me thinking, and i found out i could target the parent php page within the loaded iframe php content...it looks something like: onclick="parent.move()"...which seems to be working! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Dong!